# webupd8 oracle-java-7-installer failing with 404

Tags: java, oracle

I am attempting to install java7 in a docker image. This was working till a few days ago. Commands are:

```
    apt-get --fix-missing update
    apt-get -y upgrade

    apt-get -y install software-properties-common
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    apt-get -y upgrade
    apt-get -y update

    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
    apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer
```

Output is:

```
       Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1) ...
       debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
       debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
       debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
       debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
       debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
       debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
       Downloading Oracle Java 7...
       --2017-05-29 16:54:29--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
       Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.96.220.162, 104.96.220.106
       Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.96.220.162|:80... connected.
       HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
       Location: (REMOVING H-T-T-P-S BECAUSE I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REP POINTS)://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
       --2017-05-29 16:54:29--  (REMOVING H-T-T-P-S BECAUSE I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REP POINTS)://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
       Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.196.115.62, 2600:1408:10:184::2d3e, 2600:1408:10:185::2d3e
       Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.196.115.62|:443... connected.
       HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
       Location: (REMOVING H-T-T-P BECAUSE I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REP POINTS)//download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1496076904_47c6805122b1f8131f00e210452116ca [following]
       --2017-05-29 16:54:29--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1496076904_47c6805122b1f8131f00e21                                                0452116ca
       Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.96.220.162|:80... connected.
       HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
       2017-05-29 16:54:31 ERROR 404: Not Found.

       download failed
       Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
       dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
       subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
       Setting up gsfonts (1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1) ...
       Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1) ...
       debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
       debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
       debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
       debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
       debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
       debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
       invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
       Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
       Setting up xfonts-encodings (1:1.0.4-1ubuntu1) ...
       Setting up xfonts-utils (1:7.7+1) ...
       Setting up gsfonts-x11 (0.22) ...
       Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
       Errors were encountered while processing:
        oracle-java7-installer
       E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
       The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer'            returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: They have simple PPA way, I don't know why you tried commands like `echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections` simply `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
 `sudo apt-get update`
 `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

Comment: What is the simple PPA way you're talking about? This is using the webupd8 method. That's exactly where oracle-java7-installer comes from.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It seems that the ppa is out of data or the url to the download file has been changed.

Comment: You're likely facing a problem I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213454/not-able-to-install-oracle-jdk-on-centos-machine-using-wget/44311091#44311091

Comment: Emailed the maintainer about this, he said they won't fix it. So either upgrade to JDK8 if you want to keep using the webupd8 PPA or download & install it manually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cause of the error is Oracle's removal of the binaries from their site. Though the versions were deprecated a while ago, the binaries were still there for download until recently. But they removed it now.

This is explained in webupd8's site on June 2,2017. [Oracle's download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) says

> Updates for Java SE 7 released after April 2015, and updates for Java SE 6 released after April 2013 are only available to Oracle Customers through My Oracle Support (requires support login).
>
> Java SE Advanced offers users commercial features, access to critical bug fixes, security fixes, and general maintenance".

Check the full details here http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html.

Comment: so what about the dependencies of old pieces of the software, which points to java 7?

Comment: @Dee Which software are you talking about? No software should explicitly depends on java7, but if you find one, I can add details on how to make that work.

Answer (score 22):

Since Oracle has moved the download link and requires login credentials to download older versions of java, follow the following steps to install java 7:


1) Download latest java version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html. You will need to login.


2) Delete **jdk-7uXX-linux-x64.tar.gz** from **/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/** where **XX** is the version number.


3) Move the downloaded version into **/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/** using the following command

```
sudo mv jdk-7u(downloadedversion)-linux-x64.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/
```

4) Now run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Followed many posts nothing worked. 3rd step does the magic.

Comment: What would be the right moment to perform that overwrite? Before apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer? Obviously there is no installer yet, so how can I mv the jdk ? And if I perform the install it will fail. I can only download the package but still it will not be unpacked yet so no files in /var/cache right?

Comment: This doesn't work. It just says `E: Package 'oracle-java7-installer' has no installation candidate`.

Comment: @AugustLilleaas first you need to add the actual ppa see the original answer, then apt-get update and then you'll have the package

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the PPA doesn't help. I added it with `add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`, and that repo has no oracle-java7-installer package provided

Comment: You can use `sed` to edit the installer script in place but that isn't recommended.

Comment: I just rediscoverd this myself. Now I see this answer. :-) How did I solve it? I used this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138190/43298 approach to unpack the debian package and looked at the `postinst` script. The `fp_download_and_unpack()` function made clear that it checks for a local file in `/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer`. So I manually downloaded the tar and moved it there.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers Oracle requires a developer account or a support contract to download anything but the latest version of the JRE/JDK from their site since they typically do a release to address severe CVE (vulnerabilities).

This repository has a script that allows you to download the latest or older versions based on the parameters and environment variables you set.

https://github.com/vjkoskela/jdk-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd post here in case anyone ran into this issue with Oracle moving from Java 181 to 191 yesterday. If you're getting this issue with ***Java 8*** please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815897/jdk-8-is-not-installed-error-404-not-found/52846749#52846749) for the fix until the new Java 8 installer has been updated for Ubuntu.

Here is the fix for 181 to 191:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```