# Running apt-get upgrade or apt-get dist-upgrade fails due to Java7 installer 404

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I'm currently trying to run a upgrade or dist upgrade on my ubuntu 14.04.  The problem is it keeps trying to install the Java7 installer and [oracle took that binary out.](https://askubuntu.com/a/921390/525195)

Here is the error output

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2017-06-13 13:10:12--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 184.51.112.98, 184.51.112.96
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.51.112.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-06-13 13:10:12--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.84.148.179, 2600:1400:4:18f::2d3e, 2600:1400:4:19c::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.84.148.179|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1497373933_4797392087922e2a3b76cad4594d357c [following]
--2017-06-13 13:10:13--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1497373933_4797392087922e2a3b76cad4594d357c
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.51.112.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-06-13 13:10:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Uninstall, add the correct PPA if not already and then install Java8.

Comment: uninstall java7? or the ppa?

Comment: @nadermx: I think they meant both given that they said to then install Java8.

Comment: @MichaelBay: But you will have to clarify.

Comment: The PPA is the same. I suggest simply uninstalling `oracle-java7-installer` and use `oracle-java8-installer` instead.

Comment: uninstalling all of java 7 and installing java 8 worked.  Thank you if you want to make a answer so I can accept